# Add a required field to Registration

Tags: login

In addition to the UserName and Email address, I would like to add a checkbox that must be checked for 'I agree to this site's Terms and Agreements', in order for the account to be made.

Whats the easiest way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Show what you have tried, working or not, and where you have the problem helps us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [register_form](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/register_form) action hook.

For example:

```
add_action('register_form', 'my_required_checkbox');
function my_required_checkbox() {
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="agree" value=""> ' . __('I agree', 'lang');
    // add javascript part here
}
```

For Javascript part, take a look how to determine if checkbox is checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property).